# Eigenvector and adjoint eigenvector not orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ for which
$$
Aq = \lambda q,
$$
where $q$ is its eigenvector corresponding to a *simple* eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Consider the adjoint eigenvector $p$:
$$
A^* p = \bar{\lambda} p.
$$

How does one prove that $(p, q)\neq 0$ where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ stands for the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$? In other words, $p$ and $q$ are not orthogonal?

I came across this assertion in *Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory* [Yuri A. Kuznetsov] on page 92.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the statement is not true. Let $A$ be $2 \times 2$ identity matrix and let $q=(1,0)^T$ and $p=(0,1)^T$. Then $\lambda = \bar{\lambda} = 1$ but $q$ and $p$ are orthogonal.

Comment: I believe he's looking for an example in which the eigenvectors are orthogonal

Comment: @ekkilop Sorry, I forgot to mention that $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue. I edited the question as well.

Comment: @yanko If you check out the section 1.3 here http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kouzn101/NBA/NBA1.pdf you'll find the assertion there (right under equation (1.8)).

Comment: In the text you are referencing, the matrix $A$ is real as far as I can see. However, in your question you let $A$ be complex. Yet, you use $A^T$ (and not $A^*$) in the definition of the adjoint eigenvector. Are you certain that this is the definition you want to use?

Comment: You are right, entries of the matrix $A$ are real (that's why I used $A^T$ instead of $A^*$). I let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ so that we could talk about complex eigenvalues for which this non-orthogonality should be also true as stated in the book *Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory* (p.92). I will edit the question again, thanks for spotting this. Can you see why it's always true that $(p, q)\neq 0$ even just in the text I referenced above?

Comment: @sleepingrabbit Perhaps you should write $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix such that $0$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A$ (that is, the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is one). Let $q \neq 0$ such that $Aq = 0$ and $p \neq 0$ such that $A^{*}p = 0$. Assume that $p \perp q$. Then 
$$q \in \operatorname{span} \{ p \}^{\perp} = \ker(A^{*})^{\perp} = \operatorname{Im}(A) $$

so write $q = Av$ for some $v \neq 0$. Then $A^2v = Aq = 0$ and $q,v$ are linearly independent so $\dim \ker(A^2) \geq 2$ which implies that the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $\geq 2$, a contradiction.

For your situation, apply the above to $A - \lambda I$ and conclude that $p,q$ can't be perpendicular.

Comment: BTW, you really need to use $A^{*}$ and not $A^T$ if $A$ is complex because you are not even guaranteed that $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$, only of $A^{*}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the moment that $(p,q)=0$. There exists a unitary matrix $U$ whose first column is $q$ and second column is $p$. Then
$$
A_U := U^* A U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & + & + \\
0 & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & + & B
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $+$ denotes arbitrary matrix elements, and $B$ is a matrix of dimension $(n-2) \times (n-2)$. The eigenvalues of $A_U$ are the same as those of $A$. However, note that the characteristic polynomial of $A_U$ is 
$$
p_{A_U}(t) = (\lambda - t)^2p_B(t).
$$
Hence, the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is at least two and $\lambda$ is not simple.

Comment: This argument assumes the definition $A^* p = \bar{\lambda}p$ for the adjoint eigenvector in the event that $A$ is complex.